# Collecting follower/friend Ids of large number of users - Twitter4j

Tags: twitter, social-networking, twitter4j

I'm working on a research project which analyses closure patterns in social networks.
Part of my requirement is to collect followers and following IDs of thousands of users under scrutiny.

I have a problem with rate limit exceeding 350 requests/hour.
With just 4-5 requests my limit is exceeding - ie, when the number of followers I collected exceeds the 350 mark.
ie, if I have 7 members each having 50 followers, then when I collect the follower details of just 7 members, my rate exceeds.(7*50 = 350).

I found a related question in stackoverflow here - [What is the most effective way to get a list of followers using Twitter4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659209/what-is-the-most-effective-way-to-get-a-list-of-followers-using-twitter4j)

The resolution mentioned there was to use lookupUsers(long[] ids) method which will return a list of User objects... But I find no way in the API to find the screen names of friends/followers of a particular "User" object. Am I missing something here.. Is there a way to collect friends/followers of thousands of users effectively?

(Right now, I'm using standard code - Oauth authentication(to achieve 350 request/hour) followed by a call to twitter.getFollowersIDs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly straightforward to do this with a limited number of API calls.

It can be done with **two** API calls.

Let's say you want to [get all my followers](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids)

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?screen_name=edent
```

That will return up to 5,000 user IDs.

You **do not need 5,000 calls to look them up!**

You simply post those IDs to [users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup)

You will then get back the *full profile* of *all* the users following me - including screen name.

Comment: Thanks @Terence Eden... I was sending a request for each user id to get their details.

Comment: But still, only 100 screen names can be fetched in one request. I have so many users in my data samples who have 2000+ followers - so collecting their details would consume around 20 requests per user.. Also it takes, on an average, 20-30 seconds for each user.. So collecting the follower/following details of 32,000 users will take months :/ I think white-listing your account so that you can make 20,000 requests/hour is also not possible any more.